# Mix a video with slice of audio files (MP3, WAV) at specific offsets

Tags: python, audio, ffmpeg

I have a 1-minute video made from 1440 PNG files with:

```
ffmpeg.input('tmp/%04d.png', framerate=24).output('test.mp4').run()
```

**How to add an audio track coming from audio files, cropped, and with time offsets, with `ffmpeg-python`?**

Example:

At t=0 sec, there is no sound.

At t=12 sec, I'd like to add the first 5 seconds of `a.wav` (this file is longer originally)

At t=17 sec, there is no sound anymore

At t=25 sec, I'd like to add the first 10 seconds of `b.mp3`

etc.

I've tried with [Mono to stereo with offsets and video](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python/blob/master/examples/README.md#mono-to-stereo-with-offsets-and-video) and both positive and negative values for `atrim`, such as:

```
audio = (
    ffmpeg
    .input('a.wav')
    .filter('atrim', start=-12)     # or start=12
    .filter('asetpts', 'PTS-STARTPTS')
)
```

but it did not work: the output audio file doesn't have silence during the 12 first seconds, as desired.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/45176141/

Comment: Thank you @Gyan, how could we do it with the API of [ffmpeg-python](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python)?